How to create a gameobject from prefab in Unity
I'm trying to create a GameObject from prefab with "custom" arguments similarly to how constructors take arguments. Unity seems to go their own way on this. I found this:
public class Test : MonoBehaviour{
    public Test Init(<parameters>){
        ...;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Instantiator : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start(){
        var newTest = Instantiate<Test>(prefab).Init(<param>);
    }
}

... trying to use the code above in my code:
Master_object.cs:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Master_object : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start(){
        GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("Planet_object") as GameObject;
    
        GameObject go = Instantiate<Planet_object>(prefab).Init(1, 1, 1);
    }
}

Planet_object.cs:
using UnityEngine;

public class circle_script : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer circleRenderer;
    
    public circle_script Init(int offset_x, int offset_y, float radius){
        DrawCircle(100,offset_x,offset_y,radius);
        return this;
    }

    void DrawCircle(int steps, int offset_x, int offset_y, float radius){
        /* matching the radius of the collider with the radius of the planet.
        gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = radius ?*/
        var collider = gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        collider.radius = radius;

        // drawing the circle
        circleRenderer.positionCount = steps;
        for(int currentStep = 0; currentStep<steps; currentStep++){
            float circumferenceProgress = (float)currentStep/steps;
            float currentRadian = circumferenceProgress*2*Mathf.PI;
            float xScaled = Mathf.Cos(currentRadian);
            float yScaled = Mathf.Sin(currentRadian);
            float x = offset_x + xScaled*radius;
            float y = offset_y + yScaled*radius;
            Vector3 currentPosition = new Vector3(x,y,0);
            circleRenderer.SetPosition(currentStep, currentPosition);
        }
    }
}

ERROR:
[23:32:18] Assets/Master_obect.cs(11,50): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'Planet_object'


well your prefab is a GameObject .. so first of all you can't use it as prefab for Instantiate<Planet_object> as the signature is T Instantiate<T>(T prefab) ... then you also see it returns the same type as the generic parameter so in your case returns a Planet_object rather than a GameObject and finally your Init method returns the same type again

The error
[23:32:18] Assets/Master_obect.cs(11,50): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'Planet_object'

says that you are trying to convert a GameObject to Planet_object. The exact place where you do that is in the Instantiate method. This happens because the generic Instantiate method is declared as T Instantiate<T>(T original), and in case you use Planet_object as the generic parameter, you  have Planet_object Instantiate<Planet_object>(Planet_object original).
You show us circle_script instead of Planet_object, but I guess Planet_object is also a MonoBehaviour. MonoBehaviours and GameObjects are not in the same hierarchy of inheritance. In other words, you cannot cast a GameObject to Planet_object.
MonoBehaviours are Components. They are attached to GameObjects in editor, and there is the GetComponent method provided by Unity to get the component you need.
So, you should do the following:
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("Planet_object") as GameObject;
GameObject go = Instantiate<GameObject>(prefab);
Planet_object po = go.GetComponent<Planet_object>().Init(1, 1, 1);

here, you load prefab from resources, then instantiate this prefab to a GameObject, then you get the Planet_object component, and then you initialize it.

Actually explicitly writing out the generic parameter is probably redundant as it can be inferred from the prefab type already. This said having Init return the type seems also redundant - you could already cache this from GetComponent - but that's probably more a matter of taste .. some people swear on one-liners ;)

@derHugo totally agree with you here)) I just tried to stick to the original code as much as possible, just to not add any distractions.
